# read text from file and apply some operations on it

Tags: c#

I have a problem on how to read text from file and perform operations on it for example

i have this text file that include

//name-//sex---------//birth   //m1//m2//m3

```
fofo, male,    1986, 67, 68,  69
momo, male,    1986, 99, 98,  100
Habs, female,  1988, 99, 100, 87
toto, male,    1989, 67, 68,  69
lolo, female,  1990, 89, 80,  87
soso, female,  1988, 99, 100, 83
```

now i know how to read line by line till i reach null .

but this time I want later to perform and average function to get the average of the first colume of numbers m1

and then get the average of m1 for females only and for males only

and some other operations that i can do no problem

---

I need help i don't know how to get it
what i have in mind is to read each line in the text file and put it in a string then split the string (str.Split(','); ) but how to get the m1 record on each string
I'm really confused should i use regex to get the integers ? should i use an array 2d? I'm totally lost, any ideas?

please if u can improve any ideas by a code sample that will be great and a kindness initiation from u.

and after i done it i will post it for you guys to check.

{ as a girl I Think I made the wrong decision to join the IT community :-( }

Comment: How big is the data? i.e. how many rows? It makes a difference...

Comment: @Marc the data are like 10 lines not much
@adam its kinada of selflearning or whatever u can consider it as a HW

Comment: guys the problem I'm facing that u are so pro and using compilicated methods I'm thankful for your help but is there a way to do it using methods and ways like system.IO and regex I'm realy sorry I don't want any one of u to be upset from me

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this.

```
  var qry = from line in File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Temp\Text.txt")
            let vals = line.Split(new char[] { ',' })
            select new
            {
              Name = vals[0].Trim(),
              Sex = vals[1].Trim(),
              Birth = vals[2].Trim(),
              m1 = Int32.Parse(vals[3]),
              m2 = Int32.Parse(vals[4]),
              m3 = Int32.Parse(vals[5])
            };

  double avg = qry.Average(a => a.m1);
  double GirlsAvg = qry.Where(a => a.Sex == "female").Average(a => a.m1);
  double BoysAvg = qry.Where(a => a.Sex == "male").Average(a => a.m1);
```

Comment: Note that this will force you to load all the data into memory, which may or may not be feasible. But the approach is very similar to what I posted. Gotta love LINQ ;-p

Comment: Dontcha mean you approach is similar to what I posted ;-) given mine was posted 7 minute before yours :-). Yep LOVE linq!

Comment: Question for you though Marc, In the above I don't copy out the data to a List so my understanding was that this would just mean an itteration over the (in this case) file for each aggregate operation, so it should be processor intensive but not memory intensive, is this not true?

Comment: I'd suggest noting that this is LINQ just in case she's still on .NET 2.0.

Comment: Happy to see people loving LINQ

Comment: Sorry for delay, Tim J - I went to bed. Re the question - not true: "ReadAllLines()" forces it to buffer the entire file each time. Since the file is small, that is fine. It would be better to wrap qry = ([code]).ToArray() in this case, then you only read it once.

Comment: If you used a lazy line reader (the ReadLines method in my original post), then your statement would be correct.

Comment: @mdbritt - you can use LINQ on 2.0, as long as you have C# 3.0 - see LINQBridge

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog post a while back detailing the act of reading a CSV file and parsing its columns:

http://www.madprops.org/blog/back-to-basics-reading-a-csv-file/

I took the approach you mention (splitting the string), then use DateTime.TryParseExact() and related methods to convert the individual values to the types I need.

Hope the post helps!

Answer (score 1):

(note: this might seem an over-complicated solution, but I'm assuming that the source data is large (lots of rows), so loading it into a `List<T>` might not be feasible)

The file reading would be done quite well with an iterator block... if the data is large, you only want to handle one row at a time, not a 2D array.

This actually looks like a good fit for [MiscUtil](http://www.pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil/)'s PushLINQ approach, which can perform multiple aggregates *at the same time* on a stream of data, without buffering...

An example is below...

**why is this useful?**

Because it allows you to write multiple queries on a data source using standard LINQ syntax, but only read it once.

**Example**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using MiscUtil.Linq;
using MiscUtil.Linq.Extensions;
static class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        // prepare a query that is capable of parsing
        // the input file into the expected format
        string path = "foo.txt";
        var qry = from line in ReadLines(path)
                  let arr = line.Split(',')
                  select new
                  {
                      Name = arr[0].Trim(),
                      Male = arr[1].Trim() == "male",
                      Birth = int.Parse(arr[2].Trim()),
                      M1 = int.Parse(arr[3].Trim())
                      // etc
                  };

        // get a "data producer" to start the query process
        var producer = CreateProducer(qry);

        // prepare the overall average
        var avg = producer.Average(row => row.M1);

        // prepare the gender averages
        var avgMale = producer.Where(row => row.Male)
                    .Average(row => row.M1);    
        var avgFemale = producer.Where(row => !row.Male)
                    .Average(row => row.M1);

        // run the query; until now *nothing has happened* - we haven't
        // even opened the file    
        producer.ProduceAndEnd(qry);

        // show the results
        Console.WriteLine(avg.Value);
        Console.WriteLine(avgMale.Value);
        Console.WriteLine(avgFemale.Value);
    }
    // helper method to get a DataProducer<T> from an IEnumerable<T>, for
    // use with the anonymous type
    static DataProducer<T> CreateProducer<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
    {
        return new DataProducer<T>();
    }
    // this is just a lazy line-by-line file reader (iterator block)    
    static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string path)
    {
        using (var reader = File.OpenText(path))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                yield return line;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanx Marc but I'm not familier with using System.Linq;using MiscUtil.Linq;using MiscUtil.Linq.Extensions; but i will read about it and try to understand it thanx for your help I really I'm very thankful

Comment: MiscUtil is a bespoke library by Jon Skeet, with some input from myself. The real question here is: how large is the data?

Comment: its not large at all its max of 10 lines

Comment: Then ReadAllLines etc should be more than sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason for not creating a data structure that stores the fields of the file, a string, a boolean(for m/f), an integer and 3 integers, which you could make into a List that stores the values and then loop over it to compute various sums, averages, whatever other aggregate functions you'd like.

Comment: JB i think i got what u meant but how to do that i need more hint from u please (be patient I'm a joniur C# learner) and thanx for your help

Comment: You create a new file that will be a class file, so you could call it Person.cs if you think this is modelling a person within this system.  In there you'd define the class as having the fields of name, gender, birthyear, and m1-m3 for marks.  You then use this class within Main to hold the data.

Comment: If you don't know what I mean by a class, the idea is to have a way to represent a row as a data type, with its own unique features.  This is part of object-oriented programming, by the way.  This is assuming you don't want a quick and dirty solution.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the FileHelpers library. Check out example here: [Quick start](http://www.filehelpers.com/quick_start.html)

You could calculate the average in a foreach-loop like the one on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Suzana, I apologize in advance but I don't mean to offend you.  You already said "As a girl, you made the wrong decision to join IT...",  and I have heard that before from my sisters saying all the time when I tried to help them with their career selection.    But if you have conceptual difficulty following the above answers without just copying and paste the code, I think you just validated part of your statement.

Having said that, there are more in IT than just writing code.  In other words, coding might not just be for you, but there are other areas in IT you might excel, including becoming a manager one day.  I have had many managers who are not capable of doing the above in any language, but they do a good job of managing people, projects and resources.

Believe me, it's only getting harder from here on.  This is a very basic task in programming.  But if you realize this soon enough, you could talk to your managers asking for non-coding challenges in the company.  QA might also be an alternative.  Again, I only wish to help and am sorry if you become offended.  Good luck.

Comment: no kevin i like ur pureness view of point . thank u guys u are all kind people but I'm a bullheaded person I really want to accomplish this code and later i will think about my major , I promiss :-)

Comment: Suzana, I didn't realize you are still in school.  In that case, I would take back everything, everything I said.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Re your follow-up "what if"; you would simply loop:

```
// rows is the jagged array of string1, string2 etc
int totalCounter = 0, totalSum = 0; // etc
foreach(string[] row in rows)
{
    int m1 = int.Parse(row[3]);
    totalCounter++;
    totalSum += m1;
    switch(row[2]) {
        case "male":
            maleCount++;
            maleSum += m1;
            break;
        case "female":
            femaleCount++;
            femaleSum += m1;
            break;
    }
}
```

etc. However, while this works, you can do the same thing a *lot* more conveniently/expressively in C# 3.0 with LINQ, which is what a lot of the existing replies are trying to show... the fact is, Tim J's post already does all of this:

- ReadAllLines: gets the array of rows per line
- Split: gets the array of data per row
- "select new {...}": parses the data into something convenient
- 3 "avg" lines show how to take an average over filtered data

The only change I'd make is that I'd add chuck a ToArray() in there somewhere so we only read the file once...