# reading from a text file into a jagged array

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

I found this question in an old question in your website so i thought i can do it but I think I was mistaken :-)

the old post was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360943/read-text-from-file-and-apply-some-operations-on-it)

I'm new at the jagged array thing so did the following code

```
StreamReader rows = new StreamReader("c:\\practice.txt");
            string line;
            int i;
            i=1;
            while ((line = rows.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                String[][]rows = new String [i][]; ;
                rows = rows.ReadLine();
                String[][] rows = new string[S.Length][];
                i++;
            }
            for (int i; i < S.Length; i++)
            {

                row[i] = S[I].Split(',');

            }

            int totalCounter = 0, totalSum = 0;
            // etc
            foreach(string[] row in rows)
            {    
                int m1 = int.Parse(row[3]);
                totalCounter++;
                totalSum += m1;
                switch(row[2])
                {        
                    case "male":
                    maleCount++;            
                    maleSum += m1;            
                        break;        
                    case "female":            
                        femaleCount++;            
                        femaleSum += m1;            
                        break;    
                }
            }
```

I know i did major mistakes but at east i tried can any one help me to make it a workin code

Comment: Hardly old - it was yesterday, and still getting updated today...

Comment: I'm not convinced by the "not-homework"... in the same class as suzana or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be double-reading the lines, or maybe you've mixed up rows and cells - this bit in particular looks **really** odd:

```
        while ((line = rows.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            String[][]rows = new String [i][]; ;
            rows = rows.ReadLine();
            String[][] rows = new string[S.Length][];
            i++;
        }
```

i.e. re-declaring rows, two calls to `ReadLine` per loop, etc. I suspect you mean `string.Split`? Either way, either use `File.ReadAllLines`, or look at some of the options presented yesterday. If you are desperate to use arrays, the core might look something like:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("foo.txt");
        string[][] grid = new string[lines.Length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            grid[i] = lines[i].Split(',');
        }

        int totalCount = 0, maleCount = 0, femaleCount = 0,
            m1Total = 0, m2Total = 0, m3Total = 0,
            m1MaleTotal = 0, m1FemaleTotal = 0;
        foreach (string[] line in grid)
        {
            totalCount++;
            int m1 = int.Parse(line[3]),
                m2 = int.Parse(line[4]),
                m3 = int.Parse(line[5]);
            m1Total += m1;
            m2Total += m2;
            m3Total += m3;
            switch (line[1].Trim())
            {
                case "male":
                    maleCount++;
                    m1MaleTotal += m1;
                    break;
                case "female":
                    femaleCount++;
                    m1FemaleTotal += m1;
                    break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Rows: " + totalCount);
        Console.WriteLine("Total m1: " + m1Total);
        Console.WriteLine("Average m1: " + ((double)m1Total)/totalCount);
        Console.WriteLine("Male Average m1: " + ((double)m1MaleTotal) / maleCount);
        Console.WriteLine("Female Average m1: " + ((double)m1FemaleTotal) / femaleCount);
    }
}
```

Again - I cannot stress enough how much you should be doing this with LINQ instead of manual looping...

Comment: yesterday options are so advance I can't do it , but can you show me how to fix this

Comment: but what if i want to count the m2 and m3

Comment: thanx Marc you are the Best of the Best

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, make sure you wrap unmanaged resources such as streams in using statements.

Personally I like my [LineReader](http://csharpindepth.com/ViewNote.aspx?NoteID=113) class which makes it easy to read lines of text from a file (or anything else, actually).

Next, I'd [avoid using arrays](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx) unless you really have to. `List<T>` is generally a lot more pleasant to work with. Now if string.Split does what you want, you can easily have a `List<String[]>`. Alternatively, you can probably do a lot of the work using LINQ:

```
var query = from line in new LineReader("c:\\practice.txt")
            let parts = line.Split(',')
            select new { Gender=parts[2], Amount=int.Parse(parts[3]) };
```

Taking multiple aggregates from a single data stream is tricky in "normal" LINQ (which is why Marc Gravell and I developed [Push LINQ](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/01/04/quot-push-quot-linq-revisited-next-attempt-at-an-explanation.aspx)). However, you can use a normal foreach statement:

```
int totalCounter = 0, totalSum = 0;
int maleCount = 0, maleSum = 0, femaleCount = 0, femaleSum = 0;
foreach (var row in query)
{
    totalCounter++;
    totalSum += row.Amount;
    switch (row.Gender)
    {
        case "male":
            maleCount++;
            maleSum += Amount;
            break;
        case "female":
            femaleCount++;
            femaleSum += Amount;
            break;
    }
}
```

If you grouped the rows by gender you might be able to make this even simpler, particularly if you know that the gender is always "male" or "female".

Comment: great but can still do it by arrays

Comment: I got the PushLINQ example in yesterday ;-p

Comment: brandon: If you want an array, just call ToArray()